# Using GetListItems with Ajax call from SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to write an `ajax` call to retrieve list items from SharePoint using [Lists.asmx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists(v=office.12).aspx)

I keep getting a `302` error even though I'm folling the formatting  correctly. Am I missing something?

**Code**

```
function makeSoapCall(listName){
    var soapEnv =  
    "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> " +
    "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> " +
        "<soap12:Body> " +
            "<GetList xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> " +
                "<listName>Webpostings Approvers</listName> " +
            "</GetList> " +
        "</soap12:Body> " +
    "</soap12:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://webpub.ex.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
        });
    }
```

**Response**

```
http://webpub.ex.com/_layouts/error.aspx?ErrorText=Request format is unrecognized.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need list items . You have to use Getlistitems instead Getlist.

```
 function getSharepointListData (myList) {

       var listName = myList;

    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>"+listName+"</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Author' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http:URL/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
```